# Why do I get a blank page when I extract to csv file?

Tags: php, csv, if-statement, extract

My code works perfectly fine but when I added the if..else, it outputs a blank html page rather than extracting it to csv file.

What I did is to let the user pick an option in the dropdown list. Then I will code different csv formats depending on what the user picked.I first tried it then this happened. Can anyone please tell me what I did wrong?

This is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['extract'])){
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
    $dropdownvalue = $_POST['ship'];
    if($dropdownvalue == 'normal'){  
        $name = "sample";
        $file = $name.".csv";
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root");
        if(!$con){
            echo "Error connection";
        }

        $select_db = mysql_select_db('outbound', $con);
        if(!$select_db){
            echo "Error to select database";
        }
        mysql_set_charset("utf8", $con);

        header("Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8");
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file)); 

        $myquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM temp");

        //While loop to fetch the records
        $contents = "Name, Company, Address1\n";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($myquery))
        {
            $contents.='"'.$row['0'].'"'.",";
            $contents.='"'.$row['1'].'"'.",";
            $contents.='"'.$row['2'].'"'."\n";  
        }
        $contents_final = chr(255).chr(254).mb_convert_encoding($contents, "UTF-16LE","UTF-8");
        print $contents_final;
    }
}
```

What I added are:

```
$dropdownvalue = $_POST['ship'];
if($dropdownvalue == 'normal'){ 
I PASTE ALL THE CODE INSIDE
}
```

Before I add those, the code is working fine.

This is the dropdown list:

```
<form method="POST" action="mycsv.php">
Shipping Provider: <select id='ship' name='ship'>
<option value="normal">NORMAL</option>
<option value="val2">Value2</option>
</select>

//Button where displays datas inside the table. Not included in the problem    
<input type='button' onclick='ajaxFunction()' 
                          value='Add to Listview'/>  
//Button to extract to csv file 
<input type="submit" value="Extract CSV file" name="extract">
</form>
```

Comment: If you only see a blank page you have either display_errors turned off or your if-condition does not evaluate to true. Do you get any error messages in your logfile? Are you sure that isset($_POST['extract']) is true?

Comment: There isn't an `else` anywhere in this code... do you mean that you added the `if(isset($_POST['extract'])){
`?

Comment: what I added are     $dropdownvalue = $_POST['ship'];
    if($dropdownvalue == 'normal'){ } then put all the codes inside.

Comment: Then surely that suggests the value of `$_POST['ship']` isn't `normal`.... especially as your `mycsv` form doesn't have any field called `ship`.... there are __TWO__ forms here, only one submits a request for `mycsv.php`, the first doesn't do anything.... merge those two forms into one

Comment: ow ok. So I also need to add method = "POST" to the form where the dropdown lists are.

Comment: Don't put every field in its own separate form. You want one form, with a method of POST, an action of `mycsv.php` a submit button called `extract` and a field called `ship`

Comment: I edited it and put the "submit" button and "ship" dropdown list in the <form method="POST" action="mycsv.php">. But it's still the same.

Comment: Have you tried any debugging, to see what gets passed through to PHP in $_POST?

Comment: yes I did. I echoed what is passed in $_POST and it is exactly what I picked in the dropdown list.